# Jquery : prevent checkbox being unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to only allow the user to check checkboxes in chronological order.

```
<table id="status">
    <tr><td>Ready <input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Set <input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Go <input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
</table>
```

User is not allowed to uncheck the checkboxes and only allowed to click in the order `Ready`, `Set`, `Go`.  For this i can only add events to checkboxes and not the `td` element.

```
$("#status input[type='checkbox']").on("change",function(event) {

     if($(this).parents("tr:first").prev("tr").length==0) {
            var first_checkbox = 1;
        } else {
            var first_checkbox = 0; 
        }
        if($(this)
             .parents("tr:first")
             .prev("tr")
             .find("input[type='checkbox']")
             .is(":checked") || first_checkbox==1) {
             $(this).attr("checked",true);

        }
     }
});
```

This only allows a click if the previous checkbox is clicked but how do i prevent a checkbox being unclicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programatically this is quite simple:

1. Disable all checkboxes, **except for the first one**, at runtime
2. When a checkbox is checked, disable it after that, and enable the next checkbox

See the demo below, it should work as intended:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#status input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    // Disable all but the first checkbox
    if ($(this).closest('tr').index() !== 0) {
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }).on('change', function() {
    // Once checked, disable it
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);

    // Then enable the next checkbox
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="status">
  <tr>
    <td>Ready
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Set
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Go
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Warning: When input elements are disabled, their values are not sent when a form is submitted**. You might want to disable interaction in other ways instead of relying on the boolean attribute `disabled`. [@Rich has an alternative solution of disabling pointer events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627627/jquery-prevent-checkbox-being-unchecked/29628106#comment47399530_29628106), which I have modified my demo for. I have added some CSS styles so users can tell if a checkbox is clickable or not:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#status input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    // Disable all but the first checkbox
    if ($(this).closest('tr').index() !== 0) {
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass('disabled');
    }
  }).on('change', function() {
    // Once checked, disable it
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('disabled checked');

    // Then enable the next checkbox
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').removeClass('disabled');
  });
});
```

```css
tr {
  background-color: #BEEB9F;
}
tr.disabled {
  background-color: #FFFF9D;
}
tr.disabled.checked {
  background-color: #97C4A6;
}
tr.disabled input {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="status">
  <tr>
    <td>Ready
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Set
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Go
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice.  I had a similar solution except using CSS `pointer-events`:  http://jsfiddle.net/yudj7934/.  `disabled` seems like a better solution.

Comment: Pointer-events might be more desirable actually, depending on OP's context of using the checkboxes, because when checkboxes are disabled (or any input, really) their values are not sent when a form is submitted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disabled` attribute for the checkboxes and enable or disable them occasionally:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input', function(e) {
  var that = $(this);
  var id = that.attr('id');
  var set = $('#set');
  var go = $('#go');
  if (id == 'ready') {        
    if (!set.is(':checked') && !go.is(':checked')) {
      if (that.is(':checked')) { 
        set.removeAttr('disabled'); 
      } else {
        set.attr('disabled', true); 
        go.attr('disabled', true);
      }
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  if (id == 'set') {
    if (!go.is(':checked')) {
      if (that.is(':checked')) { 
         go.removeAttr('disabled'); 
      } else {
         go.attr('disabled', true);
      }
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="status">
<tr><td>Ready <input id="ready" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Set <input id="set" type="checkbox" disabled></td></tr>
<tr><td>Go <input id="go" type="checkbox" disabled></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but with this i can still unclick in chronological order.

Comment: Updated my answer again!

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what your looking for.

```js
$("#status input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function (e) {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    if (checkbox.is(":checked") {
        // do the confirmation thing here
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change
`$(this).attr("checked",true);` to `$(this).prop('checked', true)`
and add the following:

```
if( first_checkbox != 1 && !$(this).parents('tr:first').prev('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
   $(this).prop('checked', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example without disabling the checkboxes:  https://jsfiddle.net/t338vu33/

The checkboxes has to be unchecked or checked in a chronological order:

```
 var current = 0;

 $("#status input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function(event) {
      var selectedIndex = $('input:checkbox').index( $(this) );

     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {        
         if(selectedIndex != current)
             $(this).prop('checked', false);
         else
             current ++;
     }    
     else{      
         if(selectedIndex != current-1)
             $(this).prop('checked', true);
         else
             current --;
     }
 });
```

Comment: i can still unclick in the reverse order.

Comment: @user892134 you want to unclick from the top to bottom? it works for bottom to top?